# Can Node.js become the bottleneck in a MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, event-loop

If I were writing an application using the MEAN stack, and the database is optimized sufficiently enough to almost never be the bottleneck, can Node.js itself become a bottleneck due to the site traffic and/or number of concurrent users? This is purely from the perspective of Node.js being an asynchronous, single threaded event loop. One of the first tenets of Node.js development is to avoid writing code that performs CPU intensive tasks.

Say, if I had to post-process the data returned from MongoDB and that was even moderately CPU intensive, it sounds like that should be handled by a service layer sitting in between Node.js and MongoDB, that is not pounding the same CPU dedicated to Node.js. Techniques such as `process.nextTick()` are harder to comprehend and more importantly to realize when to use them.

Forgive me for this borderline rant, but I really do want to have a better idea of Node.js' strengths and weaknesses.